# Migration from Jest to Vitest got error "ReferenceError: DOMParser is not defined"

Tags: vitest

I migrated my test from Jest to Vitest, when I run the test, I got following error:

```js
stderr | tests/unit/parsers/XMLParserPlugin.spec.ts > parse Compacted
ReferenceError: DOMParser is not defined
    at XMLParserPlugin.parse (/Users/jianwu.chen/opensource/TreedocViewer/src/parsers/XMLParserPlugin.ts:26:19)
    at /Users/jianwu.chen/opensource/TreedocViewer/tests/unit/parsers/XMLParserPlugin.spec.ts:13:25
    at /Users/jianwu.chen/opensource/TreedocViewer/node_modules/vitest/dist/chunk-runtime-chain.0ab05798.mjs:2266:13
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, I solved this issue by adding following annotation to the test the depends on `DOMParser`.

```js
/**
 * @vitest-environment jsdom
 */
```

Also need to run:

```bash
yarn add jsdom
```

Reference: https://dev.to/mbarzeev/from-jest-to-vitest-migration-and-benchmark-23pl

Answer (score 1):

For a less file-specific option, you can set up your `vitest.config.ts` like so:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vitest/config"

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    environment: "jsdom",
  },
})
```

Ref: https://vitest.dev/config/#environment